# How can I compare schools of business between universities in terms of research productivity and impact?

Tags: publications, university, research-undergraduate

In trying to assess the learning, research and engagement opportunities of different universities at the undergraduate level (acknowledging that at undergrad level they all offer much more than the students may ever need) the websites usually provide extremely extensive rosters of faculty, and researching each teacher is frankly unwieldy.

If we were to use the number and quality of the publications; or alternatively, the number of programs available to undergrads in a discipline such as business, what would be a methodical way of going about it? Would other search-able parameters be more meaningful? Rankings in the media sound as objective as a used-car sales advisor.

For instance, I would like to focus on a concrete example, such as University of Connecticut versus Tulane University.

Comment: In the UK we have something called REF (research excellence framework), through which research quality and impact is assessed at every university over a seven year period. Universities (and departments) can then be ranked according to their REF scores. But are you specifically interested in US universities?